# Flutter row place one item at start and other item in the middle

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a card in which the first row of this card will have 2 items of text.

I would like to place an item at the very beginning and then the next item directly in the centre.

I have played around with MainAxisAlignment but nothing seems to cater for this scenario for example if I use MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween then each item is placed at the end of the rows.

Is there an obvious way how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an image for how you want the layout to look? I imagine you could just place an empty widget at the end with `spaceBetween` but it'll still be good to see what you want exactly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [Spacer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) widget to fill available space in the row:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SpacedRow(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SpacedRow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.red),
        Spacer(),
        Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.yellow),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Produces:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Though Jordan's answer achieved what the question mentioned, the yellow block does not look exactly center. I tried something like following

```
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  "images/toolbar_logo.webp",
                  width: 80,
                  height: 50,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.navigation),
              onPressed: () {},
              iconSize: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Spacer()`, `Expanded()`, `Flexible()`, `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` but here you may need to provide `padding`. There are many ways to achieve that. If you can share the screenshot or code, we can post the code accordingly.